# issue with .bst file

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am given with a template of a Journal, all the citation in my manuscript is alright  but while adding reference part all the text have become bold font. I am unable to find out if the problem is with the `.bst` file,or any problem in my part

The following commands are used
`\cite{}` for citation

```
\bibliographystyle{sa}
\bibliography{ref}
```

these two for generating references
but all reference text have become bold font
Note: As because the `.bst` file is from some other journal template, unable to share in public platform

Comment: Without your bibliography file, and an MRE, we're not going to be able to address this. Plus, it should probably be over on Tex.SE rather than here

Comment: To find out if the bibliography style is to blame, just change the style in your document, run the compilation cycle through and see if the problem manifests with the new style. If it remains, it isn't the `.bst` at fault. If not, it probably is. Does the `.bst` have a licence line? Which journal?